# Vim: ENTER takes cursor to the beginning of line

Tags: vim

If I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Vim it always takes the cursor to the beginning of line. I need it to be tab ordered just like in Visual Studio, please let me know the required settings.

Comment: Please explain what "tab ordered" means. A lot of the people who can help you with vim probably don't use Visual Studio.

Comment: `:help 'autoindent'`.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what you mean by "tab ordered"

if you mean automatically indenting on a newline in insert mode then the setting is: `filetype indent on`

if you mean to go to the first non-whitespace character on the next line in normal mode then you can use `nnoremap <CR> <CR>^`